# Sending a php variable through a url

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to pass the value of a variable called artID with href, but I'm having trouble with exactly how and where to type it. When I type it outside the PHP tags, it makes a broken link, but doesn't make a link at all when it's inside the php tags..

```
<?php
"<a href='localhost/blog/article.php?artID='$artID>";

"<a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
echo "<a href='localhost/blog/article.php?artID=" . $artID . "'>";
echo "click me";
echo "</a>";
?>
```

Comment: `echo "</a>";` at the end there.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with this:

```
  <a href="localhost/blog/article.php?artID=<?php echo $artID; ?>">Article</a>
```

The reason why your code isn't working is because you don't echo your variable, your HTML is wrong and you forgot to add a single quote.

Comment: try your code in your personal computer? its so wrong, missed quote in php and html attribute !

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='localhost/blog/article.php?artID='" . $artID . ">Click me</a>"
?>
```

this is assuming you have defined the variable and assigned its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<a href='localhost/blog/article.php?artID='" . $artID . ">LINK</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of PHP tags, the webserver won't know the value of your variable.  Inside the PHP tags, you need to echo the string...Either:

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"localhost/blog/article.php?artID=$artID\">";

echo "<a>";
?>
```

Or

```
<a href="localhost/blog/article.php?artID=<?php echo $artID ?>"</a>
```

should work